# Как передать строковую переменную в JSp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

**Выводит Hello вместо Hello World**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>web.ru.andreevda.greatOcean.MainServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```
@WebServlet(name = "MainServlet", urlPatterns = "/index")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        String name = "World";
        request.setAttribute("name", name);
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }
}
```

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello ${name}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Исходный код и jsp файлы не должны лежать в одной папке, поэтому путь `web.ru.andreevda.greatOcean.MainServlet` не должен начинаться с папкой **web**. Пример структуры проекта: [image: Пример структуры проекта]

2) В классе MainServlet реализована обработка только POST запроса, а когда в браузере прогружается html страница, то на её получение шлется GET запрос, поэтому метод надо переименовать с doPost на doGet

3) так как в файле web.xml стоят следующие конфигурационные настройки:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

то сервлет отработает например при запросе на url http://localhost:8082/123
[image: Пример на рисунке]

[ссылка на git репозиторий с рабочей версией кода](https://github.com/AlexeyOs/RuStackoverflow1029880)